# Realtime data processing with Python

Tags: python, real-time, tornado

I am working on a project which is going to consume data from Twitter Stream API and count certain hashtags. But I have difficulties in understanding what kind architecture I need in my case. Should I use Tornado or is there more suitable frameworks for this?

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what you want to do with the Tweets. Simply reading a stream of Tweets has not been an issue that I've seen. In fact that can be done on an AWS Micro Instance. I even run more advanced regression algorithms on the real-time feed. The scalability problem arises if you try to process a set of historical Tweets. Since Tweets are produced so fast, processing historical Tweets can be very slow. That's when you should try to parallelize.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. For now I am going to read a stream and lets say every 30 minutes do a calculations for new messages. And here is my problem in understanding  where should I run job for retrieving and storing messages.

Comment: If you only care about Tweets with a certain hashtag, you probably want to do the filtering as the tweets come in. In fact, if you don't care about the rest of the Tweet, you should just write a table with the counts. I find the key to processing large amounts of data is to reduce it to what you really need as it is ingested. Any analytics on that data is then pretty light weight. Of course, that means you need to decide what information you do and don't need.